# How to get the button next to the one I clicked on with MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I want to change the css properties of the button `pause` when I click on the button `stop`.

So the HTML looks like this:
[image]

And with my JS code I tried to do something using JQuery :

```
'click .stop' (event) {

        Session.set(this._id + "_spinningRng", true);
        const idDB = this._id
        const container = InfosContainers.findOne({
            _id: idDB
        });
        const name = container["nameContainer"];
        const idContainer = container["idContainer"];
        console.log("the container: " + name + " is going to be stopped. His id is: " + idContainer);

        $(event.target).closest(".pause").css({
          'background-color': 'green',
        });

        Meteor.call("container.stop", idContainer);

    },
```

But nothing happens (with the CSS part, the Meteor method call and all the stuff is working ) so I'm trying to find what I did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.closest()` takes the first parent closest to the element. Your stop and pause buttons are on the same level in the DOM-tree.

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.
>   [jQuery closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Try this instead:

```
$('.pause').css({'background-color': 'green'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't why it's not working, but if you have multiple stop/pause buttons, like in a `#each` , you can give each button a unique id and calling that in jquery `<button type="button" class="pause" id="pause-{{id}}">pause</button>`